# Blurring a Rect within a screenshot

Tags: android, opencv, android-bitmap, gaussianblur

I'm developing an Android app which uses a background `Service` to programmatically capture a screenshot of whatever is on the screen currently. I obtain the screenshot as a `Bitmap`.

Next, I successfully imported [**OpenCV**](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html) into my Android project.

What I need to do now is blur a *subset* of this image, i.e. not the entire image itself, but a [rectangular] area or sub-region within the image. I have an array of [`Rect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect) objects representing the rectangular regions that I need to blur within the screenshot.

I've been looking around for a tutorial on doing this with OpenCV in Java, and I haven't found a clear answer. The [`Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) and [`Imgproc`](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html) classes are obviously the ones of interest, and there's the [`Mat.submat()`](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#submat-org.opencv.core.Rect-) method, but I've been unable to find a clear, straightforward tutorial on getting this done.

I've googled a lot, and none of the examples I've found are complete. I need to do this in Java, within the Android runtime.

> What I need is: `Bitmap` >>> `Mat` >>> `Imgproc`>>> `Rect` >>> `Bitmap` with ROI
>   blurred.

Any experienced OpenCV devs out here, can you point me in the right direction? This is the only thing I'm stuck at.

**Related**:

[Gaussian blurring with OpenCV: only blurring a subregion of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24195138/3287204).

[How to blur a rectagle with OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26822413/3287204).

[How to blur some portion of Image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30101044/3287204).

Comment: In very simple terms, you could extract the ROI into a separate Mat, apply your filtering to that Mat and reinsert it into the original image. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I think I missed something because the question seems so simple to me! In c++ if img is your Mat and r is your Rect, then img(r) would be an image itself and you can give it to the blur function independently => blur(img(r), img(r), ksize);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C++ code to achieve this task is shared below with comments and sample images:

```
// load an input image
Mat img = imread("C:\\elon_tusk.png");
```

**img**:

[image]

```
// extract subimage
Rect roi(113, 87, 100, 50);
Mat subimg = img(roi);
```

**subimg**:

[image]

```
// blur the subimage
Mat blurred_subimage;
GaussianBlur(subimg, blurred_subimage, Size(0, 0), 5, 5);
```

**blurred_subimage**:

[image]

```
// copy the blurred subimage back to the original image
blurred_subimage.copyTo(img(roi));
```

**img**:

[image]

Android equivalent:

```
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread("elon_tusk.png");
Rect roi = new Rect(113, 87, 100, 50);
Mat subimage = img.submat(roi).clone();
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(subimg, subimg, new Size(0,0), 5, 5);
subimg.copyTo(img.submat(roi));
```

Comment: that is kinda the same what I wrote, but I gave an upvote to you anyway for more detailed answer!

Comment: Updated answer with Android code. Don't know if it works though, couldn't test it. [Look at this file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/tutorial-2-mixedprocessing/src/org/opencv/samples/tutorial2/Tutorial2Activity.java) to see how to **import** stuff from OpenCV.

Comment: Perfect input image choice

Comment: @karlphillip: thank you for taking the trouble. Your code most likely is the correct answer. Will report back after trying it out ... ;)

Comment: I don't think that you need to do a copy roi back. as far as I remember Mat subimage = img.submat(roi) shall create a pointer to the region of the original image. and if you blur subimage, you will automatically blur the original (IF YOU DONT CLONE IT).

Comment: karlphillip I've been working with your code, which I believe is correct, but I've been unable to reach the logical end. Could you please help me out with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60333766) which is a continuation of our discussion here? @hagor could you also take a look please? I will add a bounty for the same once SO lets me. Request your kind help with the same, and thank you for your time ... :)

Comment: @Y.S what do you mean by logical end?

Answer (score 3):

You could just implement your own helper function, let's call it roi (region of interest).
Since images in opencv are numpy ndarrays, you can do something like this:

```
def roi(image: np.ndarray, region: QRect) -> np.ndarray:
    a1 = region.upperLeft().x()
    b1 = region.bottomRight().y()
    a2 = region.upperLeft().x()
    b2 = region.bottomRight().y()
    return image[a1:a2, b1:b2]
```

And just use this helper function to extract the subregions of the image that you are interested, blur them and put the result back on the original picture.